# How can I add Google ads to my home page?

Tags: adsense

Guys I know this is the stupid question but need a little help, I need to put ads on my homepage as I have on my post page:

[image]

These are the ads I get on my post page (i.e `single.php`).

I also want the same thing on my home page over here:

[image]

I tried using a `<div>` tag like I did on `single.php`, but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you have your home page set up and what template are you trying to modify? Usually it is `index.php` or `home.php`, but it can also be `front-page.php` or even something completely different from defaults.

See [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#The_Template_Hierarchy_In_Detail) in Codex.

Comment: i have index.php

Comment: +1, use the existing template system to provide a home specific template, see the link in this answer.

Comment: i am not getting you,
and where is the link?

Comment: please can any one help me out here?

Comment: If you are sure you editing correct template I am out of ideas what else can go wrong.